# Installing packages using apt-get in CloudFormation file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've got the following CloudFormation script. The stack is being created and the Ec2 instance launches, and I can SSH in but it's not installing the packages.

I'm not sure where it's failing at. I'm using Ubuntu. I can't find were cfn-init is installed on my instance? Or is it only installed for Amazon Linux AMIs?

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

```
{
"Parameters" : {
    "ShinyKey": {
        "Description": "Key pair for instance.",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "Ec2Instance" : {
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "config": {
                    "packages": {
                        "apt": {
                            "r-base-dev": [],
                            "libcurl4-openssl-dev": [],
                            "git": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-9eaa1cf6",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "KeyName": {"Ref": "ShinyKey"},
            "SecurityGroups": [{"Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"}],
            "Tags": [{
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "R-Shiny-Server"
            }],
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "#!/bin/bash\n",
                            "/usr/local/bin/cfn-init --region ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            " -s ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                            },
                            " -r Ec2Instance\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access via port 22, and ports 3838 and 80 for Shiny",
            "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
                { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" },
                { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" },
                { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "3838", "ToPort" : "3838", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you should have information in the server's logs at `/var/log/cloud-init*.log`. There are two files. Also [review the three examples here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html).

Comment: Hey, maybe the following snippet will be useful:   https://gitlab.com/snippets/1864699

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue with the template above is that [`cfn-init`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) is not installed in the Ubuntu AMI, so the call to `cfn-init` in your user-data script will return "command not found" and do nothing.

The cfn-helper utilities are automatically installed only in the latest Amazon Linux AMI, as noted in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html). For Ubuntu you need to install them manually, which you can do by adding a line to your existing user-data script, after `"#!/bin/bash\n",`:

```
"apt-get update && apt-get install pip && pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
```

After this, the call to `/usr/local/bin/cfn-init` in the next line should run correctly.

Comment: I needed to sudo the apt-get commands. Also, there is now a Py3 pip download: `"sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-pip && pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [Cloudformation Init attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) in the Metadata property of the instance. The cfn-init script uses this meta data to determine what actions should be taken on boot.

In your sample code though, it does not look like you are even trying to install any packages, so I am not sure what package you are expecting to be present.