# AWS::CloudFormation::Init not installing package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to install a package when my EC2 instance initializes without success. CloudFormation doesn't throw any errors, but the package is not installed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "MyCoolServer"
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            apt:
              python: []
...
```

Comment: what is the your AMI ? ( Ubuntu  )

Comment: ami-00035f41c82244dab (ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20180912)

Comment: what is your user data? are you updating `aws-cfn-bootstrap` to latest version during initialization? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html#cfn-helper-scripts-reference-latest-version

Answer (score 0):

`cfn-init` function is now installed in your Ubuntu AMI. Then it doesn't execute.

`cfn-helper` utilities are automatically installed only in the latest Amazon Linux AMI.

More details follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101267/installing-packages-using-apt-get-in-cloudformation-file) answer.